# Check User's connections

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently working on a discord bot (using the discord.js library). This bot uses steam integration to get a user's inventory. Is there a way to check if the person has steam connected to their account and get their steam account ID? If not, how should I make sure people can link their steam account to my bot?

Comment: @Jonasw the issue there is then you van easily link someone else's steam, and fake as if the inventory they posted is theirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might search for this specific documentation/implementation [(User -> UserProfile -> UserConnection)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/UserConnection), but I wouldn't recommend using it, since it is really **instable** and you can **only use it as a normal user** not as a bot.

I would rather think about implementing a link system on your own, where user can try to link their accounts and mods must approve those linkings.

Answer (score 1):

The Discord API does not support this through Bot Accounts as far as I'm aware. As noted previously it's only possible using User accounts, though automating user accounts is against the [Discord Terms Of Service](https://discord.com/terms) and the [Discord API Terms](https://discord.com/developers/docs/legal) so I wouldn't recommend it.